# Filter out multiple images via Docker CLI

Tags: bash, docker

I am trying to list all the docker image IDs on my machine after "filtering out" two patterns.

pattern 1: docker/*
pattern 2: k8s.gcr.io/*.

This is the current list of images on my machine.

[image]

I am trying to get the final result to be

[image]

The final output would be only the "ID" of the python image.

How can I get the docker CLI to provide me this output? This solution should provide more IDs to me as the number of images that don't match the patterns above increase.

I tried to use grep but it provides me the entire output and not just the ID.

```
docker images | grep -v "docker\|k8s.gcr.io"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `awk` to filter the id only from the `docker images` output:

```
docker images | grep -v "docker\|k8s.gcr.io\|REPOSITORY" | awk '{print $3}'
```

The `$3` is the third column of next output, it will get `10fe7201ae97`.

```
REPOSITORY                TAG           IMAGE ID         CREATED             SIZE
abc                       1             10fe7201ae97     11 days ago         4.41MB
```